# Why is MongoDB not using index correctly?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection where I have a data in multi-language form like this:

```
> db.names.findOne();
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("591dbcd877d4ede22d765247"),
  "name" : [
    {
      "locale" : "de",
      "text" : "Brunhilde"
    },
    {
      "locale" : "sk",
      "text" : "Šimon"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have defined an indices for each language as:

```
db.names.createIndex({ 'name.locale': 1, 'name.text': 1 }, { name: 'name_de', partialFilterExpression: { 'name.locale': 'de' }, collation: { locale: 'de' } });
db.names.createIndex({ 'name.locale': 1, 'name.text': 1 }, { name: 'name_sk', partialFilterExpression: { 'name.locale': 'sk' }, collation: { locale: 'sk' } });
```

When I'm querying the collection as:

```
> db.names.find({ 'name.locale': 'de', 'name.text': 'Rüdi' }).collation({ locale: 'de' });
```

The query uses index, but explain plan looks a bit weird:

```
...
"executionStages" : {
  "stage" : "FETCH",
  "filter" : {
    "name.text" : {
      "$eq" : "Rüdi"
    }
  },
  "nReturned" : 1,
  "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
  "works" : 10,
  "advanced" : 1,
  "needTime" : 8,
  "needYield" : 0,
  "saveState" : 0,
  "restoreState" : 0,
  "isEOF" : 1,
  "invalidates" : 0,
  "docsExamined" : 9,
  "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
  "inputStage" : {
    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
    "nReturned" : 9,
    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
    "works" : 10,
    "advanced" : 9,
    "needTime" : 0,
    "needYield" : 0,
    "saveState" : 0,
    "restoreState" : 0,
    "isEOF" : 1,
    "invalidates" : 0,
    "keyPattern" : {
      "name.locale" : 1,
      "name.text" : 1
    },
    "indexName" : "name_de",
    "collation" : {
      "locale" : "de",
      "caseLevel" : false,
      "caseFirst" : "off",
      "strength" : 3,
      "numericOrdering" : false,
      "alternate" : "non-ignorable",
      "maxVariable" : "punct",
      "normalization" : false,
      "backwards" : false,
      "version" : "57.1"
    },
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "multiKeyPaths" : {
      "name.locale" : [
        "name"
      ],
      "name.text" : [
        "name"
      ]
    },
    "isUnique" : false,
    "isSparse" : false,
    "isPartial" : true,
    "indexVersion" : 2,
    "direction" : "forward",
    "indexBounds" : {
      "name.locale" : [
        "[\"/1\u0001\u0006\u0001\u0006\", \"/1\u0001\u0006\u0001\u0006\"]"
      ],
      "name.text" : [
        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
      ]
    },
    "keysExamined" : 9,
    "seeks" : 1,
    "dupsTested" : 9,
    "dupsDropped" : 0,
    "seenInvalidated" : 0
  }
}
```

It makes an IXSCAN, but then in FETCH stage MongoDB filters thru `name.text`.

On other hand when I make query where `name.text` is used to sort the results as:

```
> db.names.find({ 'name.locale': 'de' }).sort({ 'name.text': 1 }).collation({ locale: "de" });
```

The explain plan looks like:

```
...
"executionStats" : {
"executionSuccess" : true,
"nReturned" : 9,
"executionTimeMillis" : 1,
"totalKeysExamined" : 9,
"totalDocsExamined" : 9,
"executionStages" : {
  "stage" : "FETCH",
  "nReturned" : 9,
  "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
  "works" : 10,
  "advanced" : 9,
  "needTime" : 0,
  "needYield" : 0,
  "saveState" : 0,
  "restoreState" : 0,
  "isEOF" : 1,
  "invalidates" : 0,
  "docsExamined" : 9,
  "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
  "inputStage" : {
    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
    "nReturned" : 9,
    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
    "works" : 10,
    "advanced" : 9,
    "needTime" : 0,
    "needYield" : 0,
    "saveState" : 0,
    "restoreState" : 0,
    "isEOF" : 1,
    "invalidates" : 0,
    "keyPattern" : {
      "name.locale" : 1,
      "name.text" : 1
    },
    "indexName" : "name_de",
    "collation" : {
      "locale" : "de",
      "caseLevel" : false,
      "caseFirst" : "off",
      "strength" : 3,
      "numericOrdering" : false,
      "alternate" : "non-ignorable",
      "maxVariable" : "punct",
      "normalization" : false,
      "backwards" : false,
      "version" : "57.1"
    },
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "multiKeyPaths" : {
      "name.locale" : [
        "name"
      ],
      "name.text" : [
        "name"
      ]
    },
    "isUnique" : false,
    "isSparse" : false,
    "isPartial" : true,
    "indexVersion" : 2,
    "direction" : "forward",
    "indexBounds" : {
      "name.locale" : [
        "[\"/1\u0001\u0006\u0001\u0006\", \"/1\u0001\u0006\u0001\u0006\"]"
      ],
      "name.text" : [
        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
      ]
    },
    "keysExamined" : 9,
    "seeks" : 1,
    "dupsTested" : 9,
    "dupsDropped" : 0,
    "seenInvalidated" : 0
  }
}
```

Now the IXSCAN is followed by FETCH without filter.

Question is: **why in the first case the filter in FETCH is used and it is not enough to use just index?**

In both cases it the `indexBounds` in explain plan are the same, that can explain why in the 2nd query no filter is necessary. I didn't find any constraints in MongoDB documentation which can explain this behaviour.

**Additional information** 
When I try to use alternation of my index as:

```
> db.names.createIndex({ 'name.text': 1 }, { name: 'name_de', partialFilterExpression: { 'name.locale': 'de' }, collation: { locale: 'de' } });
```

i.e. omitting the field `name.locale` from index. It gives and interesting results, bud sadly still wrong ones. First query explain plan is:

```
...
"executionStats" : {
  "executionSuccess" : true,
  "nReturned" : 1,
  "executionTimeMillis" : 0,
  "totalKeysExamined" : 1,
  "totalDocsExamined" : 1,
  "executionStages" : {
    "stage" : "FETCH",
    "filter" : {
      "name.locale" : {
        "$eq" : "de"
      }
    },
    "nReturned" : 1,
    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
    "works" : 2,
    "advanced" : 1,
    "needTime" : 0,
    "needYield" : 0,
    "saveState" : 0,
    "restoreState" : 0,
    "isEOF" : 1,
    "invalidates" : 0,
    "docsExamined" : 1,
    "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
    "inputStage" : {
      "stage" : "IXSCAN",
      "nReturned" : 1,
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
      "works" : 2,
      "advanced" : 1,
      "needTime" : 0,
      "needYield" : 0,
      "saveState" : 0,
      "restoreState" : 0,
      "isEOF" : 1,
      "invalidates" : 0,
      "keyPattern" : {
        "name.text" : 1
      },
      "indexName" : "name_de",
      "collation" : {
        "locale" : "de",
        "caseLevel" : false,
        "caseFirst" : "off",
        "strength" : 3,
        "numericOrdering" : false,
        "alternate" : "non-ignorable",
        "maxVariable" : "punct",
        "normalization" : false,
        "backwards" : false,
        "version" : "57.1"
      },
      "isMultiKey" : true,
      "multiKeyPaths" : {
        "name.text" : [
          "name"
        ]
      },
      "isUnique" : false,
      "isSparse" : false,
      "isPartial" : true,
      "indexVersion" : 2,
      "direction" : "forward",
      "indexBounds" : {
        "name.text" : [
          "[\"KQ/9\u0001D�\u0006\u0001�\b\", \"KQ/9\u0001D�\u0006\u0001�\b\"]"
        ]
      },
      "keysExamined" : 1,
      "seeks" : 1,
      "dupsTested" : 1,
      "dupsDropped" : 0,
      "seenInvalidated" : 0
    }
  }
}
...
```

It still does filter in FETCH but via `name.locale` and not via `name.text`. The `indexBounds` changed too and contains `name.text` pattern.
Second query explain plan is:

```
...
"executionStats" : {
  "executionSuccess" : true,
  "nReturned" : 9,
  "executionTimeMillis" : 0,
  "totalKeysExamined" : 18,
  "totalDocsExamined" : 9,
  "executionStages" : {
    "stage" : "FETCH",
    "filter" : {
      "name.locale" : {
        "$eq" : "de"
      }
    },
    "nReturned" : 9,
    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
    "works" : 19,
    "advanced" : 9,
    "needTime" : 9,
    "needYield" : 0,
    "saveState" : 0,
    "restoreState" : 0,
    "isEOF" : 1,
    "invalidates" : 0,
    "docsExamined" : 9,
    "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
    "inputStage" : {
      "stage" : "IXSCAN",
      "nReturned" : 9,
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
      "works" : 19,
      "advanced" : 9,
      "needTime" : 9,
      "needYield" : 0,
      "saveState" : 0,
      "restoreState" : 0,
      "isEOF" : 1,
      "invalidates" : 0,
      "keyPattern" : {
        "name.text" : 1
      },
      "indexName" : "name_de",
      "collation" : {
        "locale" : "de",
        "caseLevel" : false,
        "caseFirst" : "off",
        "strength" : 3,
        "numericOrdering" : false,
        "alternate" : "non-ignorable",
        "maxVariable" : "punct",
        "normalization" : false,
        "backwards" : false,
        "version" : "57.1"
      },
      "isMultiKey" : true,
      "multiKeyPaths" : {
        "name.text" : [
          "name"
        ]
      },
      "isUnique" : false,
      "isSparse" : false,
      "isPartial" : true,
      "indexVersion" : 2,
      "direction" : "forward",
      "indexBounds" : {
        "name.text" : [
          "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
        ]
      },
      "keysExamined" : 18,
      "seeks" : 1,
      "dupsTested" : 18,
      "dupsDropped" : 9,
      "seenInvalidated" : 0
    }
  }
}
...
```

The `indexBounds` pattern contains min/max ranges of `name.text` (which is clear, while used in sort) and FETCH contains the filter. But ... result is wrong, documents are no more sorted by german translation as before:

```
...
{ "_id" : ObjectId("591dbcd877d4ede22d76524f"), "name" : [ { "locale" : "de", "text" : "Mathias" }, { "locale" : "sk", "text" : "Abel" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("591dbcd877d4ede22d76524e"), "name" : [ { "locale" : "de", "text" : "Rudi" }, { "locale" : "sk", "text" : "Ábel" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("591dbcd877d4ede22d765248"), "name" : [ { "locale" : "de", "text" : "Brünhild" }, { "locale" : "sk", "text" : "Žofia" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("591dbcd877d4ede22d765247"), "name" : [ { "locale" : "de", "text" : "Brunhilde" }, { "locale" : "sk", "text" : "Šimon" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("591dbcd877d4ede22d765249"), "name" : [ { "locale" : "de", "text" : "Cäcilia" }, { "locale" : "sk", "text" : "Chruňo" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("591dbcd877d4ede22d76524a"), "name" : [ { "locale" : "de", "text" : "Caecilia" }, { "locale" : "sk", "text" : "Hana" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("591dbcd877d4ede22d76524b"), "name" : [ { "locale" : "de", "text" : "Günther" }, { "locale" : "sk", "text" : "Cecília" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("591dbcd877d4ede22d76524c"), "name" : [ { "locale" : "de", "text" : "Gunther" }, { "locale" : "sk", "text" : "Zina" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("591dbcd877d4ede22d76524d"), "name" : [ { "locale" : "de", "text" : "Rüdi" }, { "locale" : "sk", "text" : "Stano" } ] }
...
```

IMHO there is really something weird by using this index in MongoDB.

Comment: Solution to the first question is to use $elemMatch operator, otherwise the query matches all the combinations of the "name" field and thus not the "locale" and "text" simultaneously. The alternative and overall "partialFilterExpression" hiccups are discussed here https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-29347 and https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23808 and https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-26580.