# Why is MongoDB treating queries differently when served from same index?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection where my documents looks like:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("591dbe4a77d4ede22d765250"),
  "name" : [
    {
      "de" : true,
      "text" : "Brunhilde"
    },
    {
      "sk" : true,
      "text" : "Šimon"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have defined an index as:

```
> db.names.createIndex({ 'name.de': 1, 'name.text': 1 }, {  name: 'name_de', partialFilterExpression: { 'name.de': { $exists: true } }, collation: { locale: 'de' } });
```

When I do a query like:

```
> db.names.find({ 'name.de': true, 'name.text': 'Rüdi' }).collation({ locale: 'de' });
```

The explain plan looks like:

```
"winningPlan" : {
  "stage" : "FETCH",
  "filter" : {
    "name.text" : {
      "$eq" : "Rüdi"
    }
  },
  "inputStage" : {
    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
    "keyPattern" : {
      "name.de" : 1,
      "name.text" : 1
    },
    "indexName" : "name_de",
    "collation" : {
      "locale" : "de",
      "caseLevel" : false,
      "caseFirst" : "off",
      "strength" : 3,
      "numericOrdering" : false,
      "alternate" : "non-ignorable",
      "maxVariable" : "punct",
      "normalization" : false,
      "backwards" : false,
      "version" : "57.1"
    },
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "multiKeyPaths" : {
      "name.de" : [
        "name"
      ],
      "name.text" : [
        "name"
      ]
    },
    "isUnique" : false,
    "isSparse" : false,
    "isPartial" : true,
    "indexVersion" : 2,
    "direction" : "forward",
    "indexBounds" : {
      "name.de" : [
        "[true, true]"
      ],
      "name.text" : [
        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It does IXSCAN followed by FETCH stage with filter. I've already created an question about the filter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44155332/311798).
The more interesting is what will happen when I just change the matching part of the query to:

```
> db.names.find({ 'name.de': { $exists: true }, 'name.text': 'Rüdi' }).collation({ locale: 'de' });
```

i.e. expression `'name.de': { $exists: true }` should be still subset of `partialFilterExpression`. As stated in documentation:

> To use the partial index, a query must contain the filter expression (or a modified filter expression that specifies a subset of the filter expression) as part of its query condition.

But the explain plan looks like this:

```
...
"winningPlan" : {
  "stage" : "FETCH",
  "filter" : {
    "$and" : [
      {
        "name.de" : {
          "$exists" : true
        }
      },
      {
        "name.text" : {
          "$eq" : "Rüdi"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "inputStage" : {
    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
    "keyPattern" : {
      "name.de" : 1,
      "name.text" : 1
    },
    "indexName" : "name_de",
    "collation" : {
      "locale" : "de",
      "caseLevel" : false,
      "caseFirst" : "off",
      "strength" : 3,
      "numericOrdering" : false,
      "alternate" : "non-ignorable",
      "maxVariable" : "punct",
      "normalization" : false,
      "backwards" : false,
      "version" : "57.1"
    },
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "multiKeyPaths" : {
      "name.de" : [
        "name"
      ],
      "name.text" : [
        "name"
      ]
    },
    "isUnique" : false,
    "isSparse" : false,
    "isPartial" : true,
    "indexVersion" : 2,
    "direction" : "forward",
    "indexBounds" : {
      "name.de" : [
        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
      ],
      "name.text" : [
        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
      ]
    }
  }
}  
...
```

As you can see index is used, but the whole filtering is happening in FETCH stage.

Question is: **why the filtering is done in FETCH stage and what is so different between these 2 queries that MongoDB them differently?**

Additionaly, sort query with `$exists` as:

```
> db.names.find({ 'name.de': { $exists: true } }).sort({ 'name.text': 1 }).collation({ locale: "de" })
```

Behaves the same, whole filtering and sorting is done after IXSCAN stage:

```
...
"winningPlan" : {
      "stage" : "SORT",
      "sortPattern" : {
        "name.text" : 1
      },
      "inputStage" : {
        "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
        "inputStage" : {
          "stage" : "FETCH",
          "filter" : {
            "name.de" : {
              "$exists" : true
            }
          },
          "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
            "keyPattern" : {
              "name.de" : 1,
              "name.text" : 1
            }
...
```

It even produces the incorrect results, while index is not used for sorting.

Comment: Using the index without collation as:

db.names.createIndex({ 'name.de': 1, 'name.text': 1 }, {  name: 'name_de', partialFilterExpression: { 'name.de': { $exists: true } } });

yields the same behaviour.

Comment: The $exists operator is always filtered in on fetched data, because on the index level MongoDB cannot distinguish between null and empty string. This is why the exists is always done in FETCH. Filtering of "name.text" has same reason as in question https://stackoverflow.com/q/44155332/311798, simply $elemMatch is necessary.